# How to redirect from google drive in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using google drive in my project for login with google.

It's working fine for me, but the problem is when user select email, in callback method user have to redirect to `'/'`, but user will redirect to `home`, this is callback method :

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    $user = User::where('email', $googleUser->email)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $googleUser->name,
            'email' => $googleUser->email,
            'password' => bcrypt(\Str::random(16))
        ]);
    }

    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);

    return $this->loggedIn($request, $user) ?: redirect(route('login'));
}
```

It's ok for next time user login with google, but for the first time redirect to `home`.

And in loggedIn function for the first time returned false because `two_factor_type` is off in default :

```
public function loggedIn(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->two_factor_type === 'on') {
        auth()->logout();

        $request->session()->flash('auth', [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'remember' => $request->has('remember')
        ]);

        if ($user->two_factor_type === 'on') {
            $code = ActiveCode::generateCode($user);
            //TODO send sms
        }

        return redirect(route('login.twoFactor'));

    }

    return false;
}
```

Even in my **LoginController** or **RegisterController** i changed this :

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

To this :

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

So why it will redirect to `home` ?

Comment: try to check the redirect url in app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. probably because your loginController@login protected with auth middleware and your current user is logged in and redirected to url in that middleware handle method

Comment: @alzafanChristian yes it's working for me, please write it in answer :))

Comment: i've put the answer, i dont know if the case-code are exactly correct xD

Comment: In this case it's working correctly :)))

Comment: glad to hear it, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` check if the controller protected with middleware, e.g:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    //meaning if there is user authenticated not guest,
    //when he hit function other than logout()
    //will be redirected to default landing, in code below
}
```

in `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated` will check if current `auth()->user() is authenticated`

change the default code to :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home'); // here change the default redirected
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check route file maybe in route file your '/' path will return home page view like below...

```
Route::get('/', function () 
{
    return view('welcome');
});
```

so please try to change this with your need.

or please remove below line from your callback function

```
return $this->loggedIn($request, $user)
```